# How to update textboxes in a listview

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I'm using MVVM for a project and I am having an issue with a specific field not updating the way I want it to. This is probably a basic problem to have but I'm stumped.

All fields are brought in from a text file, parsed, formatted, and loaded into the WPF window. I'm pretty sure the issue I'm having is XAML related as every other field works as expected.

All other textboxes work as expected but the field that's causing problems is inside a custom ListView that allows the user to select the name of an object and update all other fields with that object;s properties

This is how most of the fields are updated straightforward.

```
<controls:CustomTextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Text="{Binding SelectedViewModel.Location, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Here is the ListView I'm using to display all the object names:

```
<controls:StaticTile Title="CylName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <controls:CustomListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCyl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="530" >

          <!--<b:Interaction.Triggers>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
              <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCylChangedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding cylListBox}"/>
            </b:EventTrigger>
          </b:Interaction.Triggers>-->

          <ListView.View  >
            <GridView >
              <GridViewColumn Header="cylname" Width="250"  >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate >
                    <controls:CustomTextBox Text="{Binding CylName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="230"  Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
        </controls:CustomListView>
      </controls:StaticTile>
```

When the above TextBox, which resides in a listview, is edited, it should trigger an isDirty flag if the user attempts to switch the view to check if they want to save.

It is also meant to save on a button click which it doesn't. The reason I think it's XAML specific is that this works for every other textbox field. As you can see I tried to use a selection changed trigger in the XAML to see if I could force the view model to update when the user changed the list view but it has not worked. Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: listview and textbox seem to be custom controls. not so easy to tell if there's an error in the control template or implementation of these controls.
If all other bindings work, it could be a simple spelling error in 'CylName'...
Are there Binding errors in the Output Window when Debugging (or in VS 2019 in the XAML Binding errors window)?

Comment: @lidqy The spelling is what first came to mind so i checked multiple times and its ok. I know the bindings work because the listview textbox fills with the cylName values on load. So im thinking its an issue with the way my listview xaml is formatted thats not not allowing the viewmodel to update or recognize when changes are made to the textbox